# How to send keys to write @ on scandinavian keyboard

Tags: blueprism

I am on a scandinavian keyboard. I have been trying to write "@". And it does only work on this kind of keyboard, if you use "ALT GR + 2". But i dont know how to write it in BLuePrism, with the send global key or the send global key event.

So how do i write "@" with the use og ALT GR + 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ALT GR key on Blue Prism. But you can solve this sending:
ALT + CONTROL + 2

Answer (score 0):

however you write the '@' symbol normally you can put it into a navigate stage and Blueprism will write that symbol to screen. whatever text is in your text expression editor in the navigate stage at run time will be written to the screen you dont have to put in special operators to press the key. these special operations only really come in when they fulfill a special multi layer operation like ctrl a, ctrl c. here you can just use a navigate stage with global send keys pointed at root element with an '@' in double quotes and blueprism should write it no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send text with '@'? This can be done in an calculation stage using two sets of strings, one before @ and one after. Example: 'String1' & chr(64) & 'String2'

This is because ascii value for @ is 64, see link for more details on ascii values.

https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/at-sign-atpersand-ascii-code-64.html